# Cannot access stylesheet with handlebars

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js

I have a layout.hbs file that has a stylesheet linked to it but it doesn't seem like it is connected to the app. I already have express, path and hbs required. I might be accessing it incorrectly but my text editor is able to redirect me to the .css file path regardless. Express is using the static folder public and I tried /public and public. Both don't seem to work.

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public')));
```

My directory looks something like this

```
views
-layouts
public
-stylesheets
--layout
```

My layout hbs file looks like this

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>TITLE</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/public/stylesheets/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>HELLO WORLD</h1>
{{{ body }}}

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change the below in your code

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/public/stylesheets/style.css">
```

to

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/style.css">
```